# Searching For Multiple Values - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this the most efficient way to search multiple values at once?

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE (    (title LIKE %search term 1%)
         OR (description LIKE %search term 1%)
         OR (title LIKE %search term 2%)
         OR (description LIKE %search term 2%)
         OR (title LIKE %search term 3%)
         OR (description LIKE %search term 3%)
         OR (title LIKE %search term 4%)
         OR (description LIKE %search term 4%)
         OR (title LIKE %search term 5%)
         OR (description LIKE %search term 5%)
       )
;
```

Comment: %search% means full table scan so it doesn't matter then how much more ORs you have

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to find all records where either `title` or `description` contains any of those search terms, then that query is about as good as you can do without either (1) restructuring your schema, e.g. adding a `table_search_terms` table with columns `table_id` and `search_term` (so that you can write `SELECT table.* FROM table JOIN table_search_terms on table.id = table_search_terms.table_id WHERE search_term = 'search term 1' OR ...`), or (2) installing special tools for full-text search indexing (such as Lucene). Any smaller change, like using `INSTR` or `REGEXP` rather than `LIKE`, might speed the query up slightly (or might slow it down slightly), but will not have a very noticeable impact.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want to look into fulltext searching:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Your query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE MATCH (title,description)
AGAINST ('"search term 1" "search term 2" "search term 3" "search term 4" "search term 5"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

You'll want to define a fulltext index on your table, but it will be way faster than your original query in almost every case.